# Google Cloud SQL - Stopping / Deleting A Backup

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

How would I stop a running backup on Google Cloud SQL or delete one of the other backups? The backup has been running for over 12 hours and the instance is not accessible at all due to this.

`$ gcloud sql backups list -i mysql`

```
2016-01-08T00:00:00.138000+00:00  -      RUNNING <<-- 12h+
2016-01-07T00:00:00.376000+00:00  -      SUCCESSFUL
2016-01-06T00:00:00.713000+00:00  -      SUCCESSFUL
2016-01-05T00:00:00.943000+00:00  -      SUCCESSFUL
2016-01-04T00:00:00.249000+00:00  -      SUCCESSFUL
2016-01-03T00:00:00.575000+00:00  -      SUCCESSFUL
2016-01-02T00:00:00.015000+00:00  -      SUCCESSFUL
2016-01-01T00:00:00.257000+00:00  -      SUCCESSFUL
2015-12-31T00:00:00.890000+00:00  -      DELETED
2015-12-30T00:00:00.254000+00:00  -      DELETED
2015-12-29T00:00:00.372000+00:00  -      DELETED
```

The instance ran out of space and the backup obviously can't complete until space is freed up, so I need to free up some space first by removing a backup, then once I can actually access the instance can I free up some table space and increase the disk size.

Comment: Could you please send a email to cloud-sql@google.com and provide your instance name?  We can help you solve the issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it needs to be addressed to Google support.

Comment: If this is considered off-topic, where do you suggest I post it? There's no direct line for support unless you buy a support package which is overkill for supporting personal sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing on my side that I could do other than giving my DB a little more breathing room in the future. Tianzhou managed to stop the backup and get the instance working again, thanks Tianzhou!!